# access native QT-types with python in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I was wondering if it is possible to access native Qt-types in PyQt with an easy constructor?

### Why is this an issue?

Recently, I had an unexpected error for setting a Flag:

```
opts = 0  # in this case, no flag was set
myQMainWindow.setDockOptions( opts )
```

> *[`QMainWindow.setDockOptions()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#dockOptions-prop) expects a [`QMainWindow.DockOption`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#DockOption-enum): unexpected type 'int'*

I expected the argument to have type `int`, because when you look at `PyQt5\QtWidgets\QMainWindow.py`, you will see these dockOptions defined in the same pattern:

```
class QMainWidget(QWidget):
  AllowNestedDocks = 2
  AllowTabbedDocks = 4
  AnimatedDocks = 1
  [...]
```

### How I solved this:

I abused the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type)-function to get the underlaying class, from one of the allready known Flags, using:

```
dockOptionFlag = type(QMainWindow.AnimatedDocks) # not 'int'
opts = dockOptionFlag() # in Debug-Mode this is still shown as 'int':0
myQMainWindow.setDockOptions( opts )
```

### Why would you need something like this in general?

When I recently was translating qt-code from `c++` to `python` I realised that some Qt-classes, that are simular to python-classes, have additional functionality.

For example:

- a [`QMap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.htm) is essentialy a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) in python 
  ... but further than that, it also provieds a functionality to add entries with an existing key, without overwriting ([`insertMulti()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#insertMulti)).
- a [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) is essentialy a [`str`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str) in python
  ... but the function of [left(n)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#left), which is simular to `'someText'[n:]` is returning the entire string, if `n` is negative, which wouldn't be the case in my python translation.

I know these are simple examples and their functionality could be reimplemented in more or less time, but this is not needed since it's allready existing in the `c++`-wrapped pyqt.

---

Is their a pythonic way to access these native-types in python with an easy-constructor? 
something like: `temp = qtType("QMap", *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: No, there is nothing like this, and I cannot see any real need for it. In pyqt4, there were a few extra qt classes (such as QString), but these were all permanently removed in pyqt5 in favour of automatic conversion to python types. If you want to know what types an api requires, I suggest you firstly consult the qt docs (and maybe also the [pyqt docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/index.html)). The `QMainWindow.py` file you mention has got nothing to do with pyqt - I assume it must be some kind of typing file provided by whatever python ide you are using.

Comment: well as I said, my code ended with an error, since I gave an int, instead of an enum "int". Furthermore, you were right, the `QMainWindow.py` was autogenerated by pycharm - I somehow missed the real sip-files do to the auto-conversion of pycharm.

Comment: It's an implementation detail that enums are subclasses of python's `int`. And in general it's a bug to rely on hard-coded numeric values: enumated values should be treated as opaque, even though it is possible to perform arithmetic/bitwise operations on them. There is no guarantee that the specific numeric values will stay the same (although in practice they usually do). Having said all that, a value of the right type can be created by using the constructor: `opt = QMainWindow.DockOption(0)`. But I cannot see a good reason for ever doing that.

Comment: PS: on the subject of creating instances of QMap and such like - there is really no chance at all of this ever happening, because they are implemented as [template classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming#Templates_in_C++) in c++, and the python language obviously has nothing equivalent to that.

Comment: yeah, I missed the difference between the `Enum`-classes and the "bigger" classes like `QMap`. It seem like allmost everything from them is more or less given with the standard python features (I just needed to search deeper). Furthermore on the topic of `enums` and `flags` here is a ref. from the pyqt docs, if someone is interested: [pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/metaobjects.html#q-enums-and-q-flags](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/metaobjects.html#q-enums-and-q-flags)