# How to initialise QTextEdit find options

Tags: python, pyqt, typeerror, flags, qtextedit

I am trying to set the options in the following call:

```cpp
bool QTextEdit::find(const QString &exp, QTextDocument::FindFlags options = QTextDocument::FindFlags())
```

But the signature of `option` is complicated for a Python programmer. I tried the following:

```py
option = 0
option = option | QTextDocument.FindBackward
# continue to check other checkboxes and build up the option this way
```

Unfortunately, the error is that 'int' is unexpected. I understand that since the `option=0`, then the following OR operation probably didn't yield an int type as well. But how to get a the proper starting null/unset/zero value?

Comment: If you want help you must provide a [MRE], I have tested with PyQt4 and PyQt5 in python2 and python3 in Linux and it works correctly. You could also indicate the exact versions of the libraries you use

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49230364/984421.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by a minor bug that occasionally appears in PyQt. If you update to the latest version, the error will probably go away. However, if you can't update, or if you want to bullet-proof your code against this problem, a work-around is to initialise the variable like this:

```
>>> option = QTextDocument.FindFlag(0)
>>> option = option | QTextDocument.FindBackward
```

This will now guarantee that `option` has the expected type. The correct flag to use can be found by explicitly checking the type of one of the enum values:

```
>>> print(type(QTextDocument.FindBackward))
<class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QTextDocument.FindFlag'>
```

Or you can just look up the relevant enum in the docs: [QTextDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#FindFlag-enum).

Answer (score 2):

If you would have default value let this parameter unfilled:

```
doc = QTextDocument()
doc.find("aaa")
```

If you would like to use flag, do not read value from documentation, but use

```
QTextDocument.FindBackward
QTextDocument.FindCaseSensitively
QTextDocument.FindWholeWords
```

If you would like to have or use `|` operator:

```
QTextDocument.FindWholeWords |  QTextDocument.FindBackward
```

If you have default value in function signature, you not need to provide this argument.